# Visualization of real-time simulation process in WPF C# .NET

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, simulation

I have simulation process that consists of iterations in which simulator calculates some data and in that way, with each iterations, move thru discrete time. Beyond that simulator must in some periodic intervals update components parameters with new data. Components of simulator are used in calculation of iterations.

My current model is based on timer that have interval of 20 seconds. For each timer tick,  simulator first calculates 20 iterations as fast as possible and for the rest of time (20 seconds - time to simulate 20 iterations) it updates components parameters with new data, if new data is available. It's works very good, but...

...i implemented visualizer in WPF using MVVM pattern and I want that visualizer, once when simulation is started, show state of each iteration in right time interval. So if each iteration represents 1 second time interval I want that visualizer each second change the visualization state. I done it using timer in visualizer and buffer for states in simulator. Basically simulator enqueues calculated states in queues and visualizer dequeues states for each timer tick. It works well with some exceptions.

1. It's difficult to have constant tick interval (it depends on process, thread priority and etc.) so queue is going to infinity if visualizer timer is slower then simulator timer or other way around when vizualizer is faster.
2. Using queues adn implement code for every data that i want to visualize seems to me as implementation time overhead and memory overhead.

So I was thinking about alternative solution. That I have one timer in visualizer and for each tick of timer, asynchronously method for calculation of new iteration in simulator is called in background thread. On async callback in visualizer, visualizer refreshes visualization based on new calculated state in simulator. With this approach I have problem in refreshing components of simulator, because they need more time to refresh then one timer interval duration is. Maybe I could put refreshing of components in new background thread and once updating is done, just call method in components that will copy new value to parameters value of components.

Also the simulator is real-time so it must keep pace with real time.

It would be helpful if you can tell me what approach is better and how can I improve approaches but also if somebody have better approach I would be glad to read it and use it :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

since you are using WPF, if you use [databinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) your UI will automagically update when the data is updated--with some exceptions, mainly items in an [ObservableCollections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx).  If you are using [ObservableCollections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx), you would have to bind to each individual item in the collection. you could do that manually or write a class derived from OC that does it when you add an item and detaches when you remove an item (this is important to avoid memory leaks)

Comment: I said that i was using MVVM pattern, but I have one exception, my model doesn't have "inotify property changed" implemented in normal way. I have timer in visualizer that calls update method of view models that then reads state of simulator, and then upon change of viewmodel property, inotifypropertychanged is raisen.

Comment: have you tried automatic (the "normal" way) updates instead of manual?

Comment: I didn't because i don't want that model knows about view model because model can be used in console application, not only WPF-based app. But i was considering that model raises inotifyproperty change. Also I suppose that would consider seconds approach.

Comment: you could make it iNotifyPropertyChange... console wont care about it... you could even add some type of boolean so it "knows" its in console mode and, thus, not raise the change events

Answer (score 0):

instead of using the timer to update you can also use the databinding in wpf while you was
using the **mvvm arcitucture** and it would be nice to include the **

> inotifypropertychanged

** class
in your view model and bind the elements directly to the components so your problem will be solved